# ad Stop loss and take profit to other exit conditions

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I'm trying to add stop loss and take profit to other exit conditions. the exit conditions are respected but SL and TP do not work. Can anyone help me please?

```
tpPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + (tpPercent / 100))
slPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - (slPercent / 100))

//  Long entry
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when=longCondition,  stop=slPrice,limit=tpPrice)
if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.close("Long",  when=(D > overboughtLevel and signalLine > 0))
    

//  Short entry
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, when=shortCondition, stop=slPrice, limit=tpPrice)
if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    strategy.close("Short", when=(D < oversoldLevel and signalLine < 0))
```

I've tried several ways but I can't. Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

`stop` and `limit` arguments of `strategy.entry()` are for limit orders.

If you want to close your position based on some price level, you should use `strategy.exit()` and its `stop` and `limit` arguments.

```
if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit("LE", "Long", stop=slPrice, limit=tpPrice)
    strategy.close("Long",  when=(D > overboughtLevel and signalLine > 0))
```